# How to sort an array list of labels based on label text? JavaFX

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, collections

I am attempting to sort an array list of Label elements with text that has the following format:

"1: Consult with [someone] @14:15"

I am aiming to sort the list via the time variable, specifically the hour between the @ and : . To do this I am sorting through the array list using a for each loop, pulling the text of the label item and extracting the integer between the @ and :

After getting this , I need to run an IF statement to check if the previous Label in the Labels array has a time that is greater than the current, but I am struggling to get the previous array element within this for each loop, is this possible? My code so far:

```
for (Label label : dailyConsults){

                    String s1 = label.getText();
                    s1 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf("@") +1);
                    int thisConsult = Integer.parseInt(s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf(":")));

                    String s2 = PREVIOUS LABEL IN THIS ARRAY LIST AND GET TEXT
                    s2 = s2.substring(s2.indexOf("@") +1);
                    int previousConsult = Integer.parseInt( s2.substring(0, s2.indexOf(":")));

                    //if previous label time is greater than the current in this loop then move up
                    if(Integer.parseInt(s2) > Integer.parseInt(s1)){

                    while (dailyConsults.indexOf(label) != 0) {
                        int j = dailyConsults.indexOf(label);
                        Collections.swap(dailyConsults, j, j - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Solution: Don't use a for-each loop.

Comment: Just wondering as to why would you want to sort the `List<Label>` and not the `List<String>` which contains the text of the Labels before creating them?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, nice idea. Sorting the strings would probably give a better separation of UI and business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your `dailyConsults` is a `List<Label>` you may consider:

```
    Collections.sort(dailyConsults, Comparator.comparingInt(label -> {
        String s = label.getText();
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf("@") +1);
        return Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(":")));
    }));
```

I am using Java 1.8; in earlier versions it will take a few more lines of code, but you can use the same idea.